# file upload in angular is working but name turns into random text on upload

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, file-upload, filereader

I'm trying to upload a pdf file on an admin panel and sending it to the server on save.
For it, I'm using javascript file reader
The file uploading functionality is working fine but the name turns into random text after some time.

Initially and ideally this is how it looks

After file uploaded:

[image: After file uploaded]

But then this happens after 4-5 seconds:

File after a while:

[image: File after a while]

My .ts file for uploading and removing document

```
    isAttachment : boolean;
    attachment: any;     

    onFileChanged(attachmentInput: any) {    
    if (attachmentInput.target.files && 
        attachmentInput.target.files[0]) {
    this.attachment = '';
    Array.from(attachmentInput.target.files).forEach((file: File) => {
      console.log(file);
      this.attachment += file.name ;
      console.log('Updated', this.attachment);
    });
    
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.attachment = reader.result;
      
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.attachment);
    }
    
    }
    
    deleteFile(){ 
    this.attachment = null; 
    this.expository.attachment = null; 
    this.isAttachment = false; 
    }
```

My HTML Code:

```
<div *ngIf="expository.isAttachment == true">
    <div [hidden]="expository.id">
        <div *ngIf="attachment" class="row container-fluid ">
            <input #attachmentInput type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" class="fileInputProfile " accept=".pdf"  #fileInput  id="file"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!attachment" class="row container-fluid ">
        <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" class="fileInputProfile " accept=".pdf"  #fileInput id="file"/>
    </div>
    <div class="img-space">
        <div *ngIf="attachment">
            <div style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
                <mat-icon>article</mat-icon> {{attachment}}
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " (click)="deleteFile()"  >
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you make a stackblitz code ?

Answer (score 0):

You use the same variable `this.attachment` for file name and then for the file content. Use two variables instead. For example, `attachmentName`

```
isAttachment : boolean;
attachment: any; 
attachmentName: string = ''; 

onFileChanged(attachmentInput: any) {

  if (attachmentInput.target.files && attachmentInput.target.files[0]) {
    this.attachmentName = '';
    Array.from(attachmentInput.target.files).forEach((file: File) => {
      console.log(file);
      this.attachmentName += file.name ;
      console.log('Updated', this.attachmentName);
    });

    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.attachment = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.attachment);
  }

}

deleteFile(){ 
  this.attachment = null; 
  this.attachmentName = ''; 
  this.expository.attachment = null; 
  this.isAttachment = false; 
}
```

````
<div *ngIf="expository.isAttachment == true">
                      <!-- <mat-label>Upload Attachment</mat-label> -->
                      <div [hidden]="expository.id">
                        <div *ngIf="attachment" class="row container-fluid ">
                          <input #attachmentInput type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" class="fileInputProfile " accept=".pdf"  #fileInput  id="file"/>
                        </div>
                      </div>
          
                      <div *ngIf="!attachment" class="row container-fluid ">
                        <input type="file" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" class="fileInputProfile " accept=".pdf"  #fileInput id="file"/>
                      </div>
          
                      <div class="img-space">
                        <div *ngIf="attachment">
                          <div style="margin-bottom: 5%;">
                            <mat-icon>article</mat-icon> {{attachmentName}}
                          </div>
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger " (click)="deleteFile()"  >
                            Remove
                          </button>
    ```
````

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but this does not save the file on adding.

Comment: How do you upload file to the server?